# Agents in ORACLE DATABASE INTERGRATION

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to make stand alone agent in ODI 12G.

I have set all the credential i.e username password 'get RCU configuration' etc

But it get the following error:

[image]

```
oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.InvocationException: ODI-1424: Agent host or port cannot be reached using http://localhost:20910/oraclediagent.
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.reThrowAgentErrorAsInvocation(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:1716)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:450)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.support.InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:162)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:614)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:592)
    at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.testOdiAgent(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:85)
    at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.actionPerformed(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:76)
    at com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpAgent$5.performAction(EditFrameSnpAgent.java:637)
    at oracle.odi.ui.framework.event.OdiActionListener.actionPerformed(OdiActionListener.java:69)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ODI-1424: Agent host or port cannot be reached using http://localhost:20910/oraclediagent.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:451)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:392)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Did you start agent from OS? This post may help you http://www.canburaktumer.com/blog/odi-12c-setting-standalone-agent/

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: If your problem is solved then you are welcome. Otherwise you can give further details and we can look into problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Three things are possible:

1. You don't started the Agent. If you use standalone Agent, start first the NodeManager ( in domain home/bin directory startNodeManager.sh script), and then start the Agent Component (domain home / bin directory startComponent.sh with new_agent parameter). Did you configured (config.sh) the domain for the Agent and the Agent component after the Agent installation?
2. Your Agent Topology setup is not correct
3. You have firewall problems.